# How to link Pages in a website built using HTML & CSS Style

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

This is my code. Now how will I link the pages ourevents.html, gallery.html, about.html, contaact.html? Please help

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="2" title="">Our Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="3" title="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="4" title="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Also what is the current page? index.html?

Comment: seriously, you should learn about how to properly use hyperlinks before trying to create anything that uses them. crawl before you walk, and walk before you run.

Comment: The text of each of your link is fine, remove these empty title attributes! And there's no use for accesskeys (alas). `most key stroke combinations did in fact present a conflict for one or more of these (assistive) technologies` or if you use them then stick to this convention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_key#Use_of_standard_access_key_mappings

Answer (score 1):

Assuming current page is index.html:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="ourevents.html" accesskey="2" title="">Our Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="galery.html" accesskey="3" title="">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="4" title="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="menu">
            <ul>
                <!--// this assumes all pages are in the same directory as the cwd //-->
                <li class="active"><a href="#" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
                <li><a href="ourevents.html" accesskey="2" title="">Our Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="gallery.html" accesskey="3" title="">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="4" title="">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contaact.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)

> This is the single required attribute for anchors defining a hypertext
>   source link. It indicates the link target, either a URL or a URL
>   fragment. A URL fragment is a name preceded by a hash mark (#), which
>   specifies an internal target location (an ID) within the current
>   document.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that :

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html" accesskey="1" title="">Homepage</a></li>
    <li><a href="ourevents.html" accesskey="2" title="">Our Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="galery.html" accesskey="3" title="">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html" accesskey="4" title="">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html" accesskey="5" title="">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

What you have to do is to put the location of your page inside the href.

Comment: so would that be like this
    <a href="events.html"

Comment: yes, depending where you html file is located ex : if you file is in a folder named "website", href should look like this : "website\index.html".